# Кодировка на Java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте пишу простую программу на Java, но при компиляции в консоли выводит какие-то символы вроде этого "Р?Р?С?Р? Р?Р°С?РёР?Р°
Р?С? Р?Р?Р?Р?С?Р? РєС?РїРёС?С? Р?Р?Р?С?.
Р?С? Р?Р?Р?Р?С?Р? РєС?РїРёС?С? Р?Р?Р?Р?РєР?"

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class skillbox
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Кофе Машина");

        int moneyAmount = 120;
        int cappucinoPrice = 150;
        int espressoPrice = 120;
        int waterPrice = 20;
        int milkPrice = 100;

        boolean canBuyAnything = true;

        if (moneyAmount > cappucinoPrice)
        {
            System.out.println("Вы можете купить Капучино.");
        }

        if (moneyAmount > espressoPrice)
        {
            System.out.println("Вы можете купить Эспрессо.");
        }

        if (moneyAmount > waterPrice)
        {
            System.out.println("Вы можете купить Воду.");
        }

        if (moneyAmount > milkPrice)
        {
            System.out.println("Вы можете купить Молоко.");
        }

        if (canBuyAnything == false)
        {
            System.out.println("Недостаточно средств.");
        }
    }
}
```

Не знаю что делать, использую редактор SublimeText 3

Comment: Ну это UTF, выведенный как CP1251. Смените кодировку консоли.

Comment: Наверно нужно поменять локализацию.

Answer (score 0):

Установите в среде разработки кодировку проекта UTF-8